# How to print the contents of a child window only when the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function which opens a child window and fill it with some content using AJAX.

```
function Print(){
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {  
        //some fields
    },      
    url: 'getPageForPrint.php',
    success: function(data){
        var WinPrint = window.open('','','left=0,top=0,width=' + screen.width + 'px,height=' + screen.height + 'px,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0');
        WinPrint.document.write('<div style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">');
        WinPrint.document.write(data);
        WinPrint.document.write('</div>');

        var intervals = setInterval(function(){
            if($(WinPrint.document).find('#print_content').length > 0){
                WinPrint.document.close();
                WinPrint.focus();
                WinPrint.print();
                WinPrint.close();
                clearInterval(intervals);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

}

The problem is that the print dialogue opens before the page loaded.

I've tried to insert this code:

```
WinPrint.addEventListener('load', function(){
    console.log("Loaded!");
    if($(WinPrint.document).find('#print_content').length > 0){
        WinPrint.document.close();
        WinPrint.focus();
        WinPrint.print();
        WinPrint.close();
    }

}, false);
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.ready` method jQuery has for making sure the DOM is fully loaded before executing a function:
`$(document).ready(function)`

Pasting your function inside the `.ready()` will run the function only once the DOM is totally rendered.